# Update href inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

A modal pops up when you click on the below link.

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

The content of the modal is coming from an iframe. Now I have a anchor link inside the iframe when the user clicks on that link I want to re-direct the user to a URL. I tried window.top.location.href='www.google.com' but doesnt work.

I have the code to close the modal but if I do something like

```
 <a href="www.google.com" onclick="parent.closemodal();">iFrame
 Link</a>
```

it doesnt work.
Any thought appreciated.

Comment: I think you missed something?

Comment: I know I missed something thats the reason its not working :)

Comment: In the beginning question was quite different than after all these edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a id="tagID" href="www.google.com" onclick="parent.closemodal();">iFrame Link</a>
```

Use `document.location` to change the URL of the page you're currently on

```
$("#tagID").on("click", function(){
 document.location = "somepage.html";
});
```

Comment: I tried that but its pointing to my directory...like http://www.mydomain.com/about/meself/www.google.com.

Comment: Actually I am not trying to display google I am trying to re-direct the user to a page on my site.

Comment: I dont want to change the source of the iframe but I want to change the URL of the page.

Comment: like this <a href="www.google.com" onclick="parent.closemodal();">iFrame
 Link</a> after the user clicks on Iframe link I want to redirect the user to a page.

Comment: @Jay Then what was the problem with my original answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27134/discussion-between-evan-and-jay)

Comment: Sorry that link is blocked for me.

Answer (score 0):

www.google.com blocks viewing of their home page in an iframe. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JAPkJ/. (`<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>`) According to the console,

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

To change the URL of the page loaded from the page inside the iframe, use this:

```
document.location="http://www.example.com"
```